# skipping an item inside a loop in animation nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I'm adding items into a list using a loop, but in some cases a condition is met inside this loop that should skip that element into adding it to the list. How can this be done in AN? I've tried the loop break output but that just stops the iteration completely. I checked some python expressions and tried the `pass`statement but I keep getting syntax errors.

Any help? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generator node have a hidden *Condition* input that allows one to skip appending at a certain execution. See [example 4](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/subprograms/loop.html#example-4) in the documentation.

[image: Node Tree]